# ASP.NET Core 3.0 the right way of handling many-to-many relationship records

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The title is pretty self explanatory. When I create a new user, it should add the user to the role. My code works but it kinda looks ugly. Is there a better way to do that with one `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` call?

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public List<Bot> Bots { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateUserAsync([FromBody] UserRegisterDto userRegisterDto)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        FirstName = userRegisterDto.FirstName,
        MiddleName = userRegisterDto.MiddleName,
        LastName = userRegisterDto.LastName,
        Email = userRegisterDto.Email,
        Password = userRegisterDto.Password,
        Phone = userRegisterDto.Phone
    };

    await _context.Users.AddAsync(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Note code here
    var user2 = await _context.Users
                .Include(e => e.UserRoles)
                    .ThenInclude(e => e.Role)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == user.Id);
    user2.UserRoles.Add(new UserRole { RoleId = userRegisterDto.RoleId });
    _context.Users.Update(user2);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(new { Message = "Successfully registered." });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateUser([FromBody] UserRegisterDto userRegisterDto)
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            FirstName = userRegisterDto.FirstName,
            MiddleName = userRegisterDto.MiddleName,
            LastName = userRegisterDto.LastName,
            Email = userRegisterDto.Email,
            Password = userRegisterDto.Password,
            Phone = userRegisterDto.Phone
        };

        await _context.Users.AddAsync(user);

        var role = _context.Roles.Find(userRegisterDto.RoleId);
        UserRole userRole = new UserRole { User = user, Role = role };
        _context.Add(userRole);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(new { Message = "Successfully registered." });
    }
```